# Tryd moving average only on last candle

Tags: groovy, finance, moving-average

Tryd is a platform to operate on Brazilian stock market and accepts groovy scripts to manage some actions, like draw candle sticks or line on stock graphs.

My problem is, when I use moving average function to draw a line based on candle-stick close price, the entire line the varies with the last data. I tried to create a new line data and save previous value, but without success. There are a way to handle this?

I want to save last value, and the Moving Average line only changes on last candle-stick.

Comment: Which graphing library are you using ? Update your question with your code so that we can help you.

Comment: you want to show some code

Comment: it's not a graphical lib, it's a software tryd.com.br